# How to test sensor application in android AVD?

Tags: java, android, sensors, proximity

I am developing a android proximity application using eclipse and Android AVD but I am not able to test proximity application in AVD.

Is there any other way to test proximity application and other sensor application?

Note: My computer USB is blocked so i am not able to connect physical device also

Comment: AVD cannot test a lot of Android features, especially sensors. Change to a computer with non-blocking USB, and debug it with real device. Alternatively, make a `.apk` and install in a real device & diagnose with on-screen debug messages

Comment: register the proximity sensor to `SensorManager` and once registered, you will get call sensor values in `onSensorEvent()` continuously with sensor values equal to the maximum range of proximity Sensor...

Comment: @GopalRao OP is asking about AVD...

Comment: You don't need usb to test on a device-  adb can also connect via bluetooth or wifi.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Yes. I know. and my comment is also with respect to AVD. I have tested one of my app which uses proximity... My AVD is `4.0" WVGA (480X800 hdpi)` with target as `Android 4.1.2`...

Comment: @ShivanRaptor : fine. I will create a apk and will install in my physical device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AVD cannot test a lot of Android features, especially sensors.

In case the USB is unavailable for debug in physical device, you can:

1. change to a computer with non-blocking USB, and debug it with real device.
2. make a .apk and install in a real device & diagnose with on-screen debug messages
3. enable "ADB over Network", then you can debug the app with Bluetooth / Wi-Fi network